# Cocos2dx v3.4 Release Mode Error

Tags: c++, cmake, cocos2d-x, release, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to build my game on release mode using CMake. I disabled DEBUG_MODE and successfully built the project but when I run it I get an error I don't get in debug mode.[image: Error Message]

Here's the call stack.

```
KernelBase.dll!763d2f71()   Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]    
    [External Code] 
>   SortingGame.exe!BackgroundBuilder::configureTimeLabel(const cocos2d::Vec2 timeContainerEndPos) Line 236 C++
    SortingGame.exe!BackgroundBuilder::configureTimeContainerSprite() Line 226  C++
    SortingGame.exe!GameScene::configureTimeContainerSprite() Line 352  C++
    SortingGame.exe!GameScene::configureScene() Line 210    C++
    SortingGame.exe!GameScene::init() Line 130  C++
    SortingGame.exe!GameScene::create() Line 25 C++
    SortingGame.exe!LoadingScreen::onKeyPressed(cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event * event) Line 168   C++
    [External Code] 
    SortingGame.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 24   C++
    [External Code]
```

`BackgroundBuilder::configureTimeContainerSprite()` function gets called only once. If I call `BackgroundBuilder::configureTimeContainerSprite()` in `BackgroundBuilder::BackgroundBuilder()` the error doesn't occur in `BackgroundBuilder::configureTimeContainerSprite()` but in main.cpp file's `return Application::getInstance()->run();` line. The error is the same here too.
I get the same error when I build the project with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I managed to get a detailed stack log. Here it is --> https://paste.kde.org/pqttvvxkm

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It appears that there's a problem with the way I pre-load assets into my game. In the `TitleScreen::init()` I use this function to load assets.
`GameManager::getInstance()->getResourceManager()->loadTextures("GameScene", callback);`
And here's the implementation for the `CocosResourceManager::loadTextures()`

```
void CocosResourceManager::loadTextures(const std::string &sceneName, const std::function<void(std::string sceneName, int loadedAssetCount, int totalAssetCount)> &callback)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> assets = parseAssetsArray(sceneName);
    int totalAsset = assets.size(), loadedAsset = 0;
    for (auto value : assets) {
        TextureCache::getInstance()->addImage(value.second);
        loadedAsset++;
        callback(sceneName, loadedAsset, totalAsset);
    }
}
```

When I don't pe-load the assets with that function, there's no crash in release mode. When I pre-load them, I have it with the stack trace I previously posted above. This happens with both `TextureCache::getInstance()->addImageAsync();` and `TextureCache::getInstance()->addImage();`
Am I pre-loading the wrong way? Can anybody explain why this is happening?